# using "offset" parameter in yelp v1 API to get more results?

Tags: javascript, yelp

I want to use "offset" parameter in yelp version1 Api to get next set of results.

without using "offset" i get 20 results?How can i get more?

api like this:

http://api.yelp.com/business_review_search?term=hotels&lat=40.70590473669712&long=-73.9780035&radius=2&limit=20&ywsid=myywsid

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The short answer is you cannot.
http://www.yelp.com/developers/documentation/search_api
`Default is 10. Minimum value is 1 and maximum value is 20` 
and the `offset` call is only for v2.0.
While on v1.0 you must use `limit`